# How to change visual studio code tooltip background color

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code editer :https://code.visualstudio.com/ for windows. I am trying to change background color of tooltip message box but i could not do it.Below my code but not working.Anybody can help me to resolve this issue?

settings.json

```
 {  
 "vscode_custom_css.imports": ["./style.css"],
 "vscode_custom_css.policy": true
 }
```

style.css:

```
      /* suggest-widget size */

      .monaco-editor .suggest-widget.docs-side {
      width: 1000px; 
      }

      .monaco-editor .suggest-widget.docs-side > .details {
      width: 60%;
      max-height: 800px !important; 
      }

      .monaco-editor .suggest-widget.docs-side > .tree {
      width: 30%;
      float: left; 
      }

      /* parameter-hints-widget */

      .editor-widget.parameter-hints-widget.visible {
      max-height: 800px !important; 
      }

      .monaco-editor .parameter-hints-widget > .wrapper {
      max-width: 1000px; 
      }

      /* editor-hover */

      .monaco-editor-hover .monaco-editor-hover-content {
      width: 1000px;
      height:500px;
      background-color: aqua;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times your own edits on `.vscodestyles.css` doesn't overwrite to the defaults, so here is my solution (Editing the default css):

- <kbd>f1</kbd> -> Developer tools.
- Pull up a tooltip, then select it in developer tools.
- In developer tools, see the source of background-color. It might be the default. If so, open it in developer tools.
- Copy a part of the file (a substring). With this trick, you'll be able to search for it and go straightly to the right place later in the editor.
- Open it in an editor with write premission. Search for the substring you copied, change the css, then save it.

It's good to copy the edited css some where, this way after updates, you can easily change the default css.

Comment: Very difficult to find the tooltip css bg color

Comment: I need using "vscode_custom_css.imports" because i am creating tooltip application for vs code..many people will use that so userfriendly must

Comment: @cinnan Use element selector (ctrl + shift + c) in developer tools.
When you found the item in the css file, just scroll in the menu on bottom right of developer tools to find bg color.